# How to toggle button on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

In my application I have an arrow button where when user first lands into the page he can see with a down arrow when he clicks on the button I need to change the image to up arrow when he again clicks it should be changed to down arrow how can I do this

```
<button type="button" id="btnfilterparameters" class="buttonFilter primaryColor">
  <span class="f18">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  Search
</button>

$("#btnfilterparameters").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive"); //here i need to change the arrows on click
  if ($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")) { //here i need to change the arrows on click

  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find('span.fa')` will find the span inside the button element

```
$("#btnfilterparameters").click(function () {
  $(this).find('span i.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down');
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsbin.com/noqirutexe/edit?html,js,output

Refer:

- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: then here how should i handle if ($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")) {
           
        } else {
           
        }

Comment: but this is not working it is not changing the arrow on button click

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Check `$(this).find('span i.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down'); });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnfilterparameters").click(function () {
 if($(this).hasClass('btn-success')){
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-down')
    .addClass('fa fa-angle-double-up');
    console.log('set btn-warning')
  }else if($(this).hasClass('btn-warning')){
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-up')
    .addClass('fa fa-angle-double-down');
    console.log('set btn-success')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="btnfilterparameters" class="btn btn-success">click me
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> </button>
```

You can use javascript's hasclass(), addclass() and removeClass() function.

```
$("#btnfilterparameters").click(function () {
  $(this).find('span.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down');
 if($(this).hasClass('fa-angle-double-up')){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-double-up');
    $(this).addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
  }
});
```

Comment: then here how should i handle if ($(this).hasClass("buttonActive")) { } else { }

Comment: Initially, you provide the default class, up or down whatever, then upon every click, call the change function

Comment: can you show with code and fiddle i have done but not working

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the answer. I'm refactoring it more.

Comment: Similarly, you can use you angle up/down class. Better to use Bootstrap button toggle behaviour.